# TOMCAT HTTP Status 403 - Access to the specified resource() has been forbidden

Tags: tomcat6, http-status-code-403

Recently I moved a application into different Tomcat server environment and for some users who are accessing my application outside network getting Status 403 access forbidden error. Intranet users have no issues, only few outside network users alone facing this issue.Even i tested it from outside network and its working fine for me. Tomcat version is 6.0.18. Please help me to find some idea about this issue.There is no credential for login into this application.

Successful user getting below log
IP Address - - [16/Jul/2015:08:27:20 -0500] "POST /AppName/Main.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 12403

Other user(facing issue) getting below log
IP Address - - [16/Jul/2015:08:30:16 -0500] "GET /AppName/Main.jsp HTTP/1.1" 403 964

I don't know how its getting changed with "GET" & "POST" for different users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause of this issue, In that new server those particular IPs are being blocked for some reasons through context.xml.